# How to add elements from a list to a two-dimensional array?

Tags: java, list, int

I have a list of ints that I need to add to a two-dimensional array.

```
ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>(size);

//Generation
if(size % 2 != 0) {
    System.out.println("need nombre pair");
} else {
    int x = 0;

    while (x != 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i >= size/2; i++) {
            int n = (int)Math.random() * 10;

            if(!myList.contains(n))
                myList.add(n);

        }

        x++;
    }
}

Collections.shuffle(myList);
```

Once my list is shuffled, I want to add all the ints to a two-dimensional array (`int[][]`). How do I do this?

Comment: What kind of table, a `JTable`?

Comment: do you mean an array? by (int[])

Comment: I have this:

int[][] tab = new int[][];

I want to add the list in that table.

Comment: I see. What you are calling a table is a *two-dimensional array*. But let's continue using table nomenclature - how do we know which row to put the integers in?

Comment: @Duncan, I just had a word-gasm, nice!

Comment: At the start I ask how many rows and columns the user wants (2x2 - 8x8) so basicly if he enters 4x4, I want an array that looks something like this:

1 2 3 4
2 5 1 3
5 4 6 6
7 8 7 8

The liste already contains 2 of each numbers.

Comment: if the user asks for a 4x4, i want something like this: http://imgur.com/BgirYhU

Comment: Where is your sorting algorithm?  What sorting algorithm are you trying to implement?

Comment: 1. Ask user amount of rows and columns
2. Generate numbers between 0 and 31 and add them twice to the list until the list contains rows*columns amount of numbers (every number is there twice)
3. take this list and turn it into a 2d array so it looks like this imgur.com/BgirYhU so I can associate images to then in a gridLayout panel for a memory game.
note**: the numbers are sorted with 
Collection.shuffle(myList);

Comment: Let's say I have created an array with 4 columns and 4 rows, I want images behind these question marks associated with the numbers in the Array. http://imgur.com/6LzYlBp

Comment: @user3472686 "*Generate numbers between 0 and 31*" > why is 31 chosen here? Suppose there were 3 rows of 7 columns, i.e. 21 total cells. What numbers would we fill that with? If it's an odd number of cells, you can't have every number twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method that will generate a 2D array that meets your requirements:

```
private static int[][] makeArray(int columns, int rows) {
  int totalItems = rows * columns;

  if (totalItems % 2 != 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must be an even number of cells.");
  }

  List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
  for (int i = 0; i < totalItems / 2; i++) {
    numbers.add(i);
    numbers.add(i);
  }

  Collections.shuffle(numbers);
  Iterator<Integer> iterator = numbers.iterator();

  int[][] result = new int[columns][rows];

  for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
      result[x][y] = iterator.next();
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Here's a small main method to test it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  int[][] array = makeArray(3, 4);

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array[i]));
  }
}
```

Example output:

```
[0, 5, 1, 0]
[3, 1, 5, 2]
[4, 3, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split your list into multiple subLists and convert those into arrays, one for each column of the table:

```
Integer[][] table = new Integer[width][];
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        table[x] = myList.subList(width * x, width * x + height).toArray(new Integer[height]);
    }
```